# Is Python set more space efficient than list?

Tags: python

`list` is known to initialize with a big chunk of space to optimize the time needed to expand the list (on average we don't have to keep making new list like an array).

What about `set`?

The following construction makes it space wasted because of `list`. I understand `tuple` is more space saving because it is immutable. Can we do the same to `set` and still mutable?

`set( [ 1, 2, 3] )`

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> from sys import getsizeof as size
>>> s = set(xrange(100))
>>> l = list(xrange(100))
>>> size(s)
8424
>>> size(l)
1016
```

`set`s take up *more* memory than `list`s. Some of the functionality that `set`s offer requires more memory (e.g. quick membership tests).

Comment: That's interesting. Looks like it has to keep more things.... for whatever reason.

Comment: [PySetObject](https://github.com/schmir/python/blob/2.7/Include/setobject.h#L34) vs. [PyListObject](https://github.com/schmir/python/blob/2.7/Include/listobject.h#L22)

Comment: Getting quick (probably logarithmic) membership test requires more memory. Membership test in lists is certainly linear in time.

Comment: Also it seems the last test is flawed—it returns 64 on my machine regardless of test size.

Comment: @liori Strange (happened with me too). One of the drawbacks of `getsizeof` I suppose. Deleted that test.

Comment: ImmutableSet's implementation uses a dictionary under the hood, and size of a dictionary holding `xrange(100)` is over 12kB on my machine. So it isn't more space efficient.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that for small lists, sets can take up 10x as much memory, but in larger lists this goes down to around 3x for some reason. (Maybe from hash table collisions resulting in linked list chaining, which would slow down lookup, but help memory usage?)

In python3, getsizeof(range()) always returns a constant because range objects are sort of like iterators, so I tried testing this out by making the actual lists.
EDIT: I could have tried using getsizeof(list(range()))

```
from sys import getsizeof # returns memory size in bytes
list_lengths = [100, 1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000, 10000000, 100000000, 1000000000] # from 100 to 1billion
for length in list_lengths:
     my_list = [num for num in range(length)]
     my_set = set(my_list)
     print("list length: {}".format(len(my_list)))
     print("memory size of my_list: {}".format(getsizeof(my_list)))
     print("memory size of my_set: {}".format(getsizeof(my_set)))
     print("set to list size ratio: {}".format(getsizeof(my_set)/getsizeof(my_list)))


Output:
list length: 100
memory size of my_list: 912
memory size of my_set: 8416
set to list size ratio: 9.228070175438596
list length: 1000
memory size of my_list: 9024
memory size of my_set: 32992
set to list size ratio: 3.6560283687943262
list length: 10000
memory size of my_list: 87624
memory size of my_set: 524512
set to list size ratio: 5.985939925134666
list length: 100000
memory size of my_list: 824464
memory size of my_set: 4194528
set to list size ratio: 5.087581750082478
list length: 1000000
memory size of my_list: 8697464
memory size of my_set: 33554656
set to list size ratio: 3.8579815909557085
list length: 10000000
memory size of my_list: 81528056
memory size of my_set: 268435680
set to list size ratio: 3.2925558779421897
list length: 100000000
memory size of my_list: 859724472
memory size of my_set: 4294967520
set to list size ratio: 4.995748824048828
list length: 1000000000
memory size of my_list: 8058558880
memory size of my_set: 34359738592 # my computer doesn't have this much memory, not sure what's going on here. Maybe it's writing to SSD
set to list size ratio: 4.263757218089594
```